# Could not determine recommended JdbcType - Quarkus

Tags: java, hibernate, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I'm trying to add a new JPA Entity to a quarkus project but I'm getting the below error. Unfortunately the error is so cryptic that it doesnt really give any clear indication as to where or what the problem is.

```
Error running Quarkus: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.StartupActionImpl$1.run(StartupActionImpl.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:70)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:44)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:124)
    at io.quarkus.runner.GeneratedMain.main(Unknown Source)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to start quarkus
    at io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.spi.JdbcTypeRecommendationException: Could not determine recommended JdbcType for `org.acme.employeescheduling.domain.Contract`
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.spi.UnknownBasicJavaType.getRecommendedJdbcType(UnknownBasicJavaType.java:37)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.internal.InferredBasicValueResolver.from(InferredBasicValueResolver.java:222)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.BasicValue.buildResolution(BasicValue.java:480)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.BasicValue.resolve(BasicValue.java:310)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.BasicValue.resolve(BasicValue.java:300)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.lambda$processValueResolvers$4(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1831)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.removeIf(ArrayList.java:1682)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.removeIf(ArrayList.java:1660)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processValueResolvers(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1830)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1816)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:328)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.boot.FastBootMetadataBuilder.build(FastBootMetadataBuilder.java:406)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.PersistenceUnitsHolder.createMetadata(PersistenceUnitsHolder.java:101)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.PersistenceUnitsHolder.constructMetadataAdvance(PersistenceUnitsHolder.java:73)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.PersistenceUnitsHolder.initializeJpa(PersistenceUnitsHolder.java:40)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.HibernateOrmRecorder$1.created(HibernateOrmRecorder.java:78)
    at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.ArcRecorder.initBeanContainer(ArcRecorder.java:79)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.ArcProcessor$generateResources844392269.deploy_0(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.ArcProcessor$generateResources844392269.deploy(Unknown Source)
    ... 16 more
```

The entity I'm trying to add is very simple - with types being `string` and `long`.

```
@Entity
public class Contract {
    
    @Id
    @PlanningId
    @GeneratedValue 
    private Long id;
    
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    private String code;
    private String description;   
        


        public Contract() {
        }

        public Contract(long id) {
            this.id = id;
            
        }

        public Contract(long id, String code, String description) {
            this.id = id;
            this.code = code;
            this.description = description;
        }

        public String getCode() {
            return code;
        }

        public void setCode(String code) {
            this.code = code;
        }

        public String getDescription() {
            return description;
        }

        public void setDescription(String description) {
            this.description = description;
        }


        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return code;
        }

}
```

It would be really appreciated if someone could advise on how to extract something meaningful and useful from the stacktrace.

Comment: Thanks @Luca Basso Ricci - I think that may have been the problem.